# How can I remove the bottom bar from Mathematica?

Tags: customization, dialog-window

There is a bar with a zoom button on it, and it takes too much room. How can I disable it?

Appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > "Advanced" tab > Open Option Inspector

In the Option Inspector's sidebar, drill down to Notebook Options > Window Properties.

For the WindowElements option, uncheck "StatusArea" and "MagnificationPopUp".

Here's what your Option Inspector should look like:

[image]